# How to disassemble movb instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, objdump, i386

I am writing a disassembler and I was reviewing the instruction format (and doing some disassembling by hand) and I ran into an instruction that I can't seem to be able to decode.

The output for that particular instruction (from objdump) is:

```
c6 05 14 a0 04 08 01    movb   $0x1,0x804a014
```

However, I dont understand how the instruction is decoded, since the opcode c6 is supposed to be MOV Eb Ib (Mod R/M to imm8).

Can somebody enlighten me as to how it is decoded?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers! The 3 are really complete, I hate to choose only one since all of them answered my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained (in part) by Alex Frunze's answer, but his is a bit terse, so I will provide some explantation here:

1. The opcode is c6/0, which indicates that there are 2 operands to the instruction. One is an r/m 8, which means an operand encoded in mod/rm byte, and an immediate operand. Both operands are 8 bits wide.
2. The /0 in the opcode means that part of the opcode is encoded in the mod/rm byte. Bits 3-5 in the mod/rm byte are part of the opcode. When you have c6 followed by a mod/rm byte whose bits 3-5 have the value 0, you get an mov opcode.
3. The value 5 (the byte that immedietly follows c6), corresponds to an r/m byte of 00 000 101 (in binary).
4. The "last three" (bits 0-2) of the r/m byte correspond to the r/m field. An r/m value of 101 (5) means "use a displacement dword", so the next 4 bytes following the mod/rm byte form an immediate address.
5. 14 a0 04 08 is the little endian encoding of 0x0804a014
6. The last byte 1 is the immediate value to load into the address

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I completely missed the entry in the table (somehow read it as a register and not disp32).

Answer (score 3):

Well, moving *to* an immediate doesn't mean anything.  What that instruction does is move a constant 1 into the memory byte located at 0x804a014.  Something like the equivalent C code:

```
*(unsigned char *)0x804a014 = 1;
```

You've got opcode `c6`, as you know.  You can look that up as part of the `MOV` instruction in [Volume 2A of the docs](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

The `05` is the ModR/M byte.  You can decipher that using [Table 2-2 of volume 2A](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), "32-Bit Addressing Forms With the ModR/M Byte".  Look for `05` in the "Value of ModR/M Byte (in Hexadecimal)" part of the chart.  Trace left from there, and you'll see that the effective address for this ModR/M value is given in 'disp32' form.  The footnote there says "The disp32 nomenclature denotes a 32-bit displacement that follows the ModR/M byte".  In this case that's the next four bytes of your instruction: `14 a0 04 08`.

Finally, you have the 8-bit immediate `01`, and the complete instruction is decoded.

Answer (score 3):

c6 - opcode (there's also a part of opcode in Mod/RM byte, in /digit(reg) field)
05 - Mod/RM byte (mod=00b, r/m=101b, /digit(reg)=0 - part of opcode)
14 a0 04 08 - disp32
01 - imm8

And it's a `mov` from `Ib` to `Eb`. You're probably confusing the AT&T syntax, in which objdump is showing the disassembly, with that of Intel/AMD documentation. The order of operands in AT&T syntax is the opposite of that in x86 CPU manuals.

Comment: Yeah, I still mix them up a lot (consequence of using different references), sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the answer.